# Why GridSearchCV returns nan?

Tags: cross-validation, pipelines, gridsearchcv

I am using gridsearchcv to tune the parameters of my model and I also use pipeline and cross-validation. When I run the model to tune the parameter of XGBoost, it returns `nan`. However, when I use the same code for other classifiers like random forest, it works and it returns complete results.

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)

SCORING = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1' ]

# define parametres for hypertuning
params = {
    'Classifier__n_estimators': [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
}

XGB = XGBClassifier()
UnSam = RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours()

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('UnderSampling', UnSam ), ('Classifier', XGB)])
# ___________________________________________

mod = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv =kf, scoring = SCORING, refit='f1', return_train_score=True)
mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is my code and when I run it, the following results are obtained:

```
{'Classifier__n_estimators': 5}
__________________________________________________
F1 :  [nan nan nan nan nan nan] 
 Recall :  [nan nan nan nan nan nan] 
 Accuracy :  [nan nan nan nan nan nan] 
 Precision :  [nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

Another thing that is weird is that when I apply the same code for tunning the penalty in Logistics Regression, it returns nan for l1 and elasticnet.

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)

SCORING = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1' ]

# define parametres for hypertuning
params = {
    'Classifier__penalty': ['l1','l2','elasticnet']
}

LR = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
UnSam = RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours()

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('UnderSampling', UnSam ), ('Classifier', LR)])
# ___________________________________________

mod = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv =kf, scoring = SCORING, refit='f1', return_train_score=True)
mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The results are as follows:

```
{'Classifier__penalty': 'l2'}
__________________________________________________
F1 :  [  nan 0.363   nan] 
 Recall :  [   nan 0.4188    nan] 
 Accuracy :  [   nan 0.7809    nan] 
 Precision :  [   nan 0.3215    nan]
```

Answer (score 10):

By default, `GridSearchCV` provides a score of `nan` when fitting the model fails.  You can change that behavior and raise an error by setting the parameter `error_score="raise"`, or you can try fitting a single model to get the error.  You can then use the traceback to help figure out where the problem is.

For the `LogisticRegression`, I can identify the likely culprit: the default `solver` is `lbfgs`, which cannot handle L1 or ElasticNet penalty.  Use `saga`.

I don't immediately see an issue with the XGBoost model or parameters.  Get the error traceback using the first paragraph, and search/ask that as a separate question if needed.

Comment: useful info. upvoted. But, do you know why does a model fit fail in the 1st step? If you refer the linked post below, it provides gridsearchCV score for some CV executions but it is again `nan` for some. Can you help with this? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/109322/how-to-gridsearchcv-on-balancedbagging-classifier